# How do I pass value from REST API to Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, api, rest, leaflet

Hlo,I am trying to parse the elevation value from REST API to a leaflet map that contains the API with lat, lon. The link to REST API is:-https://developers.airmap.com/docs/elevation-api. I am not able to get the value for elevation for the point location. Anybody please help me to fix it.The code is given as:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Creating mash-ups with Leaflet</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://auth.airmap.com/js/keycloak.js"></script>
   <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #map {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 1000px;
            }
        </style>
   <head>
    <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script >
      var map = L.map('map').setView([14.6361111, 42.1608333], 8);
    var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/web_map_service/mapserv?', {
    layers: 'GEBCO_LATEST_SUB_ICE_TOPO'
    }).addTo(map);

var elevation;

$.getJSON('https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/collections/ogr_gpkg_poi/items?f=json', function (value) {
        var datalayer = L.geoJson(value,{
          onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {
            var lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
            var lon = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
            var city = feature.properties.name;
            
            $.ajax({
              url: 'https://api.airmap.com/elevation/v1/ele/?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + 
              '&units=metric& appid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjcmVkZW50aWFsX2lkIjoiY3JlZGVudGlhbHxwQUFNWlBxaEx2T2Q2cGZSR2JkMlhDQkdRcTdNIiwiYXBwbGljYXRpb25faWQiOiJhcHBsaWNhdGlvbnx3ZURHZ01oTldtek55c1A4S0xEdlRsQW5QTE0iLCJvcmdhbml6YXRpb25faWQiOiJkZXZlbG9wZXJ8MnpvYmI3eWh4ZVk0cWtDM1BSeDBaSEtNejIzOCIsImlhdCI6MTQ3MTM3OTc0Mn0.MeO0jt6holPt0jdPJvRJrTBi380WsbOPGCEO6u-tfSo',
              async: false,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (json) {
              elevation = json.data;
              }
            }); 
            featureLayer.bindPopup("City: " + city + "</br>Elevation: " + elevation + "metres");
          }
        }).addTo(map);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You are using the API in a wrong way. If you read carefully [the documetation](https://developers.airmap.com/docs/elevation-api) you will see that the request you are trying to attempt expects `?points=' + lat + ',' + lon +` and not `?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon +`. Also the same API accepts multiple points at the same time so you don't have to make 10 requests as you are doing right now via a for loop and possibly do only one. Because you are doing them in a synchronous way you will see that the browser is frozen until all of them are resolved. Last but not least , as it was implied in a comment the coordinates you receive is in the form of `[lon,lat]` and not `[lat, lon]` so you will need to switch the variables you are storing them

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Creating mash-ups with Leaflet</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://auth.airmap.com/js/keycloak.js"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 1000px;
    }
  </style>

  <head>

    <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([14.6361111, 42.1608333], 8);
        var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/web_map_service/mapserv?', {
          layers: 'GEBCO_LATEST_SUB_ICE_TOPO'
        }).addTo(map);

        var elevation;

        $.getJSON('https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/collections/ogr_gpkg_poi/items?f=json', function(value) {
          var datalayer = L.geoJson(value, {
            onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {
              var lon = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
              var lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
              var city = feature.properties.name;

              $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.airmap.com/elevation/v1/ele/?points=' + lat + ',' + lon +
                  '&units=metric& appid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjcmVkZW50aWFsX2lkIjoiY3JlZGVudGlhbHxwQUFNWlBxaEx2T2Q2cGZSR2JkMlhDQkdRcTdNIiwiYXBwbGljYXRpb25faWQiOiJhcHBsaWNhdGlvbnx3ZURHZ01oTldtek55c1A4S0xEdlRsQW5QTE0iLCJvcmdhbml6YXRpb25faWQiOiJkZXZlbG9wZXJ8MnpvYmI3eWh4ZVk0cWtDM1BSeDBaSEtNejIzOCIsImlhdCI6MTQ3MTM3OTc0Mn0.MeO0jt6holPt0jdPJvRJrTBi380WsbOPGCEO6u-tfSo',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                  elevation = json.data;
                }
              });
              featureLayer.bindPopup("City: " + city + "</br>Elevation: " + elevation + "metres");
            }
          }).addTo(map);
        });
      </script>
    </body>

</html>
```